# Why is this HasField instance not being resolved?

Tags: haskell, records

I'm using **GHC 8.2.1**. I have the following module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Moat (Moat,moat) where

import GHC.Records (HasField(..))

newtype Moat r = Moat r

moat :: r -> Moat r
moat = Moat

instance HasField s r v => HasField s (Moat r) v where
    getField (Moat r) = getField @s r
```

And this other one:

```
module Foo (Foo(..)) where

data Foo a = Foo { getDims :: (Int, Int), getData :: [a] }
```

My problem is that when I have both modules imported and I try to do something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Moat
import Foo
import GHC.Records

oops :: (Int,Int)
oops = getField @"getDims" (moat (Foo (5,5) ['c']))
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (HasField "getDims" (Moat (Foo Char)) (Int, Int))
       arising from a use of ‘getField’
```

Why is the `HasField` instance not being resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved by enabling `{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}` in the `Moat` module which defines the `HasField` instance.

I suppose it has to do with `HasField` typeclass being poly-kinded:

```
λ :info HasField
class HasField k (x :: k) r a | x r -> a where
    getField :: r -> a
```

This allows us to define `HasField` instances like this one, where the field selector is  a non-`Symbol` type:

```
import GHC.Records
data A = A B
data B = B deriving Show
instance HasField B A B where
    getField (A b) = b
```

In ghci:

```
λ> getField @B (A B)
B
```