# Deriving Via: Cannot derive well-kinded instance

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

I am encountering this error when I try to derive an instance.

```
Cannot derive well-kinded instance of form ‘HFunctor (ControlFlowCMD ...)’
    Class ‘HFunctor’ expects an argument of kind ‘(* -> *, *)
                                                  -> * -> *’
• In the newtype declaration for ‘ControlFlowCMD’
```

I am trying to do this:

```hs
newtype ControlFlowCMD fs a = ControlFlowCMD (ControlCMD fs a)
  deriving HFunctor via (ControlCMD fs a)
```

You can see the data type and instance I am basing my type on and trying to derive [here](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/imperative-edsl/blob/master/src/Language/Embedded/Imperative/CMD.hs), on line 278. I am not that used to using deriving via - could anyone explain what this error means and how I would fix it?

Comment: @chi Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have tried that. The error message does not change.

Comment: @Robert Do you have `DataKinds` and/or `PolyKinds` enabled? That `(* -> *, *)` seems like a kind-level tuple and might require them.

Comment: @danidiaz Enabling either change nothing, but enabling both made it pass. Thanks! I am used to GHC screaming at me which extensions I need, but now it couldn't figure out that these were the extensions I need.

Comment: @Robert I had a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659560/1364288 and yes, it's a pity that GHC doesn't warn you on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `(* -> *, *)` or, equivalently, `(Type -> Type, Type)` is a kind-level tuple, and one must enable the [`DataKinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=datakinds#extension-DataKinds) and [`PolyKinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=datakinds#extension-PolyKinds) extensions in order to handle it. (I'm not completely sure why `PolyKinds` is needed though; maybe it's to allow more general kind inference.)

With datatypes having complex kinds, it's often a [good idea](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2020/01/05/five-benefits-to-using-standalonekindsignatures/) to enable [`StandaloneKindSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=datakinds#extension-StandaloneKindSignatures) and give the kind signature explicitly:

```
import Data.Kind
type ControlFlowCMD :: (Type -> Type, Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype ControlFlowCMD fs a = ...
```